# $http call is not returning any data to the element

Tags: angularjs

Here is the code:

```
var app = angular.module('componentsApp', []);

app.directive('components', ["$http", function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "component.html",
        controller: function() {
            this.heading = "Available Data";
            this.results= [];

            $http.get("data.json").success(function(data) {
                this.results = data;
            });
        },
        controllerAs: 'component'
    };
}]);
```

Components.html

```
<h3>{{ component.heading }}</h3>
<div ng-repeat="result in component.results">
    <span>{{ result.name }}</span>
    <span>{{ result.description }}</span>
</div>
```

When I run it, the icons variable shows up as empty. I would imagine this has to do with an issue of the data now existing in the time the element is constructed by the directive since the $http call uses promises.

Can anyone confirm this? If so, what would the solution be?

Comment: Can you add the relevant parts of component.html? Also, what is the `icons` variable?

Comment: how can you access outer this context in your $http....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when you do: `this.results = data;` in callback of `$http`, this is not refers to your controller, but to callback scope. So you can try something like this:

```
app.directive('components', ["$http", function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "component.html",
        controller: function() {
            var vm = this;
            vm.heading = "Available Data";
            vm.results= [];

            $http.get("data.json").success(function(data) {
                vm.results = data;
            });
        },
        controllerAs: 'component'
    };
}]);
```